# Inter-subquery communication in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying to figure out if there is any mechanism by which you can **directly** (not through some other mechanisms) pass some data between 2 sub-queries in a big query, like this:

```
select CustomerID, (select PostalCode from Customers where ContactName = S2.ContactName)
from Customers
where ContactName in (select ContactName
                        from Customers where City = 'London') S2
```

Where I want to use the data from S2 in the first sub-query.

Note: the query above should not return anything meaningful, my inquiry is just into how SQL sub-queries work.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  There is no doubt some direct way to do what you want; what is unclear is what you want.

Comment: the question is about how sql server passes data between sub-queries, not about how to achieve some goal

Answer (score 1):

you can use cte and for inner query use aggrgation in case of multilple result

```
with cte as
(
select ContactName
 from Customers where City = 'London'
)
select CustomerID, 
(select max(PostalCode) from Customers where ContactName = c1.ContactName
)
from Customers c
join cte c1 on c.ContactName=c1.ContactName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select CustomerID,
       max(case when City = 'London' then PostalCode end) over (partition by ContactName) as london_postalcode
from Customers
where ContactName in (select ContactName
                      from Customers
                      where City = 'London'
                     ) ;
```